# toggleAttribute not supported in IE

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, event-listener

I have a situation where when a user selects a checkbox it is supposed to disable an input field. I wrote the following code that works wonderfully in all other browsers except IE which I didn't know was most important for the client.

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let button = document.querySelector(".checkbox");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.toggleAttribute("disabled");
});
```

Can someone help me with something that will also work in IE? Much appreciated.

Comment: check if its already toggled. input.disabled = input.disabled ? false : true;

Comment: Use the pollyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE you need to use `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` since toggle is not supported.